# android appium optionalIntentArguments multiple boolean extra params

Tags: appium-android

Appium for android has optionalIntentArguments capability. The question is I would like to pass in multiple Boolean extra parameter (--ez). Anyone know how to do that ? Thank you

I have tried

```
--ez IN_APP_USAGE_ENABLED true --ez WEB_DASHBOARD_IS_SHOW true
--ez IN_APP_USAGE_ENABLED true, --ez WEB_DASHBOARD_IS_SHOW true
--ez IN_APP_USAGE_ENABLED true, WEB_DASHBOARD_IS_SHOW true
--ez IN_APP_USAGE_ENABLED true WEB_DASHBOARD_IS_SHOW true
--ez [IN_APP_USAGE_ENABLED true, WEB_DASHBOARD_IS_SHOW true]
```

they always return with error in appium

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method to use :

```html
capabilities.setCapability("optionalIntentArguments","--ez IN_APP_USAGE_ENABLED true --ez WEB_DASHBOARD_IS_SHOW true");
```